# Generic way to generate random struct for testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, automated-tests

I've been given the task to refactor a bunch of C++ code that has a lot of math and not an explanation of what it does. 
In order to do that I've setup a bunch of automated test that given random data compare old and new code results.

The thing is that, while it is simple to generate random vector of any size I have a lot of "struct" with many public fields (> 20) I'm a bit tired of writing custom function to fill them.

One can think of using some kind of script to parse the definition and autobuild the corresponding generator function.

Do you think this is a good idea ?
Is there anything like that already done?

Comment: I guess the proper term for this kind of tests would be *fuzzing*. But before writing tests to compare old and new code you probably should figure out what does existing code do and write tests to check its correctness.

Comment: Probably I should but I can not. The best thing I can do now is to ensure that the results are the same than before.

Comment: What I have done is to add reflection to the struct (boost hana or similar, [visit_struct](https://github.com/cbeck88/visit_struct)) and add a visitor to fill random value according to its type (and sometime with member name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only [Plain Old Data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType), a struct is, roughly, merely a blob of memory with some meaning to the compiler.

This means you can treat it as such, and simply fill it with random bytes, using a union:

```
struct a {
    int i;
    char c;
    float f;
    double d;
};

union u {
    char arr[sizeof(a)];
    a record;
};

char generateRandomChar(); // implement some random char generation

int main() {
    u foo;
    for (char& c : foo.arr) {
        c = generateRandomChar();
    }
    std::cout << "i:" << foo.record.i 
              << "\nc:" << foo.record.c
              << "\nf:" << foo.record.f
              << "\nd:" << foo.record.d;
}
```

[See it live!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/286d2b675975f9b3)

Technically, this is [Undefined Behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). In practice, it is well defined in most compilers.

Comment: If you know already it is UB with a union, why don't you mention the alternative: memcpy?

Comment: @Andre good question. I thought about it, but you'd still have to generate the (pseudo)random bytes somehow. Probably one by one, as most libraries (including the standard library, as far as I know) do. If I'm already generating them one by one, why would I store them in a different memory location just so I can `memcpy` them?

Comment: of course, if you can generate them in bulk, it would be a nice performance increase, with a (probably) small memory cost.

Comment: I was thinking about this. Probably using memcpy is more correct  but this will do the stuff. Thanks!